# HTML expanding boxes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create three boxes with some short text and when you click on one of those boxes, it will expand on the full width of the page and displays the whole content. Then it can be closed by clicking on some kind of icon.

I created a gif so you can see what I mean. [GIF](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3941/vfm43loz_gif.htm)

I have so far the basic structure on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bszv7f90/)

When you click on one box it every time opens the box-3 content insted of the content of the clicked box. Also I dont know how to close the open box.

Is the animation you can see in the gif possible with css or does it need javascriptl?

```
$(".row.boxes-container .box").click(function (e) {
        $(".box-content-full").addClass("open");
    });


.row.boxes-container{
    position:relative;   
}

.box:hover{
    cursor:pointer;   
}

.box-content{
    padding:30px;
    background-color:#f03939;
}

.box-content-full{
    display:none;   
    width:0%;
    transition: width 1s;
}

.box-content-full.open {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    display:block;
    transition: width 1s;

}

.box-content-full.open .inner{
    padding:30px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
    background-color: red;

}


<div class="container">
        <div class="row boxes-container">

            <div class="box first">
                <div class="box-content-full">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="inner-header">
                            <span class="close">x</span>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Box 1</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolem filum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <h3>Box 1</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box second">
                <div class="box-content-full">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="inner-header">
                            <span class="close">x</span>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Box 2</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolem filum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <h3>Box 2</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box third">
                <div class="box-content-full">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="inner-header">
                            <span class="close">x</span>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Box 3</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolem filum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <h3>Box 3</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not use your html code but tried to get a result as close as possible to your gif:

```js
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    
    var $openElement = $('<div class="absoluteBox"></div>');
    
    $openElement.css('left', $element.position().left);
    $openElement.css('right', $element.width());
        
    $element.html($openElement);
    
    $openElement.animate({left : 0, width : $('.wrapper').width()}, 500);
   
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.box {
    background-color:#CC0000;
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
 }

.box:last-of-type {
    margin-right:0;
}

.absoluteBox {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    height:200px;
    width:150px;
}

.box:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I made the opening box blue to be better noticed. This has to be changed via css of course to red.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle:

EDIT 2:
Now it should reset when you click the box.

P.S. Click the second box for the effect.
P.P.S. The effect displays incorrectly because the page contracts automatically in JSFiddle. ALTHOUGH, if you try it elsewhere and it doesn't work, consider me proven wrong!

EDIT:
Updated answer to expand element that was clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/bszv7f90/9/

```js
$(".row.boxes-container .box").click(function(e) {
  $(this).children().each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'box-content-full') {
      $(this).toggleClass("exp");
    }
  });
  $(".box-content-full").toggleClass("open");
  $(".box-content").toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
}
.row.boxes-container {
  position: relative;
}
.box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box-content {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #f03939;
}
.box-content-full {
  display: none;
  width: 0%;
  transition: width 1s;
}
.box-content {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #f03939;
}
.box-content.clicked {
  display: none;
}
.box-content-full.open {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 0%;
  width: 0%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  transition: width 1s;
}
.box-content-full.open.exp {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  transition: width 1s;
}
.box-content-full.open .inner {
  padding: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row boxes-container">

    <div class="box first">
      <div class="box-content-full">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="inner-header">
            <span class="close">x</span>
          </div>
          <h3>Box 1</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolem filum</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box-content">
          <h3>Box 1</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box second">
      <div class="box-content-full">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="inner-header">
            <span class="close">x</span>
          </div>
          <h3>Box 2</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolem filum</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box-content">
          <h3>Box 2</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box third">
      <div class="box-content-full">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="inner-header">
            <span class="close">x</span>
          </div>
          <h3>Box 3</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolem filum</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box-content">
          <h3>Box 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now it should expand.
I preserved your code to make a quick copy-paste.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bszv7f90/11/

I tried to achieve a functioning close button. But for some reason it wont work. I copied your code which adds the css classes to the opening box and so on. I thought I could turn it around somehow, so that the classes will be removed by clicking on the x.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: updated my anser to toggle class on click, working on closing on X.

Comment: now it closes no matter where you click. Unfortunately something is wrong with it. At first it opens the right content box, but if you close it and click on the other boxes, at some point it will start to open the wrong content.